# timer issue at displaying view

Tags: iphone

hi i am new to iphone. what i am doign is displaying 20 images as grid and by selecting image it is displayed on imageview after 4 sec it will come back to main screen,for that i am using timer it works fine but there is a small problem with out selecting image the timer is continually running.if i am selecting button on 2 sec late then with in remaining 2 sec it will come back how can i solve this pls help me

Comment: You need to accept more answers on your quesitons, it is currently too low.

Comment: Can you show some code to see when and how you start the timer?

Comment: my code is 
----------
atimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.0 
             target:self
           selector:@selector(runscheduledTask)
           userInfo:nil
            repeats:YES];
// i write this in viewdidload
-----------------------------------

 - (void)runscheduledTask {
  
  
 NSLog(@"timer");
 @try {  
 
 
 CustomImagePickerAppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    UINavigationController *navController = [delegate navController];
    [navController pushViewController:_imagePicker animated:YES];
  
  }

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having the timer continuously running, only start it when the user selects an image. That way you get the full 4 seconds. Also, make sure you set it not to repeat.

Comment: how can i set it and where can i place it

Answer (score 0):

In the selector you're calling with your timer, you need to invalidate that timer. That means you need to assign the timer to a property in your view controller, so you can talk about it later. So say you've got an ivar of `NSTimer *backTimer`, then in the method that the timer calls, you'll say `[backTimer invalidate]`, and that timer will go away.

You should also invalidate it when somebody backs out of the "full image" view. Probably in `-viewDidUnload` or `-viewDidDissapear`.